# How can I configure ZSH to start each shell with an isolated, empty history?

Tags: shell, zsh, command-history, oh-my-zsh

I use ZSH with Oh My Zsh. I would like each new ZSH shell to start with an empty history. Commands typed in one shell should never show up in the history of another shell. How can I achieve this?

I've tried appending the following to my `~/.zshrc` to no avail:

```bsh
setopt no_share_history
unsetopt share_history
unsetopt inc_append_history
unsetopt append_history
```

I have also tried following this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/691603/287342) to make the arrow keys only show local history, but that seemed to have no effect.

Currently, if I open a new shell, it imports history. I cannot seem to delete the history; when I delete `~/.zsh_history`, it re-appears with the entire old content once I open a new shell. `inc_append_history` does prevent history from being written right away, but the history will still eventually be saved once the shell is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zsh history is only saved if you set both the `HISTFILE` variable (to the path of the history file) and `SAVEHIST` variable (to the amount of entries to store there).

So it should only be a matter of removing those variable definitions from wherever they're being set (probably your `~/.zshrc` or any file included from there). Even not setting only one of them would be enough.

Note that `setopt no_share_history` and `unsetopt share_history` (or `set +o nonosharehistory`, etc or `options[sharehistory]=off`) are strictly equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. I think I like this approach more because, if I understand correctly, it prevents history from being written in the first place. For posterity, I appended `unset SAVEHIST` to my  `~/.zshrc` and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @bgfvdu3w, note that those variables are not set by default, so it must be set by some of your startup scripts. You could run `zsh -x` from within `script` and then do `grep -we HISTFILE -e SAVEHIST typescript` to figure out where it is.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```
function erase_history { local HISTSIZE=0; }
erase_history
```

It will erase the history each time you start an interactive zsh shell.

Comment: Somehow I missed this ingenious solution. I had come across how to clear history before. However, I was too focused on preventing it from being written in the first place so I did not consider just clearing it every time I start a new shell.

Comment: You could shorten that to `(){ local HISTSIZE=0; }`